# Calling a WCF Service without a Service reference

Tags: wcf

I have a project A which has a Service reference to a WCF Service. I want to invoke the service in project B without a Service reference.
From what I understand, the Service reference is just a way to generate the proxy and config and is not used at run-time.
I copied the proxy class and the  node from project A to project B.

Can I just create an instance of the proxy class in project B and expect it to directly use the config. items and connect to the service without anything else?
(I cannot try this right now)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer yes.

As long as you have the interface, a way to connect to the service, you can create a channel and talk to service without having the reference.

The reference simply makes it easier for you to develop against.

Comment: By "way to connect to the service" do you mean just network availability of the web service or some .NET class I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

Look into creating channels from your service contracts with [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576132.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working copy. For me it works fine and returns List

```
private List<MyClass> GetAllSiteDetailsJSON(string language)
{

   Uri address = 
            new Uri(@"http://weburlpath/MyService/MyService.svc/GetAllList/"
                                                                   + language);
   HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
   request.Method = "GET";
   request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

   using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
   {
       StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
       string jSon = reader.ReadToEnd();
       reader.Close();

       JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       List<MyClass> result = jsSerializer.Deserialize<List<MyClass>>(jSon);
       return result;
   }
}
```

And Here is the class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```